Should thesis defense slideshow be shared?
As mentioned in Academia.SE, it is encouraged to share one's thesis manuscript and publish it online. What about a PhD defense slideshow? I am quite glad with the work we did on this presentation and it has, I believe, at least the same quality of the ones I did during conferences at that time.
The only con I see is that a slideshow is often not self-sufficient and must be accompanied with a speech, which would explain why few thesis defense are shared online from what I have seen.
On the other hand, in my particular case, I believe that someone reading my manuscript or our articles could  understand more easily thanks to the TikZ graphs and other figures on the slideshow.
Finally, maybe the best is to ask the supervisors' thoughts about it?

Ask your supervisor. That said, I see no reason not to do this.

There is no particular reason why you can't share this, though not the best idea for patentable ideas (US perspective). It would be hard to find a publisher, I think, other than your own web pages.
You could put a copyright notice in it, and/or a license if you really wish it to be shared.
While the talk that accompanied it may be essential or not, note that you can add subtitles to the essential pages and include a link to the thesis itself if it is available.
